# How can i do this oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Statement: "Customers who have purchased a full series license"

Tables:

```
SERIES:
title           
total_seasons

SEASONS:
title           
season      
avgduration 
episodes 
PRIMARY KEY (title, season),
FOREIGN KEY (title) REFERENCES SERIES

LIC_SERIES:
id_client
datetime
title
season
episode 
PRIMARY KEY (client,title,season,episode)
FOREIGN KEY (title,season) REFERENCES seasons
```

Series example looks like this:

```
Title     Total_Seasons
House     8
Lost      6
```

Seasons example looks like this:

```
Title    Season AvgDuration Episodes
House    1      44          22
Mad Men  3      47          13
```

Lic_Series example looks like this:

```
Client   Datetime   Title Season Episode
92/657/T 01/01/2017 House 8      18
```

*What i tried?*

```
WITH PART AS (SELECT DISTINCT EPISODES, TITLE
FROM SEASONS INNER JOIN SERIES
ON Seasons.Title = Series.Title
GROUP BY Seasons.Title)

SELECT CLIENT 
FROM LIC_SERIES INNER JOIN PART
ON LIC_SERIES.TITLE = PART.TITLE
ORDER BY title DESC;
```

I do not know how to check if a customer has all the episodes of each season, and all the seasons of the series in question

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? And SELECT DISTINCT combined with GROUP BY is rarely never useful - only for experienced users!

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and also its expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This would return the number of episodes owned and not owned by each client of each season. To check whether all episodes are owned, do an additional check of the summary where episodes_not_owned is zero

```
WITH PART AS 
(SELECT DISTINCT s2.TITLE, s1.SEASON, s2.EPISODE
FROM SEASONS s1
INNER JOIN SERIES s2
ON s1.Title = s2.Title
)
,summary as (
SELECT l.CLIENT
      ,p.SEASON
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN l.episode is not null THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as episodes_owned
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN l.episode is null THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as episodes_not_owned
FROM LIC_SERIES l
RIGHT OUTER JOIN PART p
ON l.TITLE = p.TITLE
AND l.EPISODE = p.EPISODE
AND l.SEASON = p.SEASON
GROUP BY l.CLIENT, p.SEASON
ORDER BY l.CLIENT, p.SEASON DESC
)
SELECT s.client
      ,s.season
      ,s.episodes_owned
      ,s.episodes_not_owned
      ,case when s.episodes_not_owned = 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as all_owned
from summary s;
```

Comment: It says: `Error SQL: ORA-00904: "S1"."EPISODE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action: `  @Jeremy Real

Comment: @Junior I've updated to pull episode from s2 rather than s1. Was referencing wrong table. Your table description calls the field 'episodes', but your query used 'episode'. You may need to update that field name if it's supposed to be plural.

Comment: You're right its plural. Now the error is with s2! xD  `Error SQL: ORA-00904: "S2"."EPISODE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:`  But its ok i think i can work with this (lets hope that)

Comment: @Junior It looks like episode should also be plural